# Index out of range even thought element exists

Tags: python, list, csv, index-error

I have csv file with list of servers presented like this:

> 929912,"172.83.40.219","System.Object[]","System.Object[]","Canada#944","ca944.nordvpn.com","0","CA","Canada"

from which I need extract several values. I'm opening file with csv reader, but if I try to access any element apart from first using index, for example row[1](ip address), python returns IndexError.
But if i cycle through the row, I get every element:

```
with open('servers.csv') as f:
read_data = csv.reader(f)
for row in read_data:
    for i in row:
        print(i)

> 929912
> 172.83.40.219
> ...
```

Is there a way access values without for cycle?

Comment: If I have a csv file with just that example line, `row[1]` works. But if I also have an empty line there, there is obviously only one element for that line and `row[1]` fails. Are you sure this isn't happening in your case? What does `print(row)` say before you do `row[1]` when it fails? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If I just do print(row) I get a full list of values literally as a list 
[929912,"172.83.40.219","System.Object[]","System.Object[]","Canada#944","ca944.nordvpn.com","0","CA","Canada"]. So every other string of values in the file processed as a list, from which I cant call value by index, but I can get it through cycle.

Comment: I don't understand at all what you're trying to achieve. `row` clearly has enough elements to not raise an `IndexError`. Where and how do you get that error? What is the full traceback? Please provide us with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try

> row = next(reader_data);

or

> row= reader_data.next();

It should read the whole row to row and then you can do row[1] like you want.

Comment: you can also say reader_data= csv.reader(open("servers.csv"))

Comment: You are only restating what the OP has done. But it seems while iterating over his rows, at some point `row[1]` fails.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:
First you can cast into list

```
with open('servers.csv') as f:
    read_data = csv.reader(f)
    read_data_list = list(read_data)
    ip = read_data_list[0][1]
```

The second option and the best for me is using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ('servers.csv', sep=',')
ip = df.columns[1]
```

Comment: Your first suggestion just restates the code. If `for row in reader: row[1]` fails at some point, casting it to a list and then doing `read_data_list[some_index][1]` *will fail*.

Comment: First option doesnt work, same error persists. Second processes file differently, doesnt work as you described, i get out of bounds error.

Answer (score 0):

Each row is a list of entries which you can access with its index. So your thought with `row[1]` to get IP address should work, perhaps you were just accessing it at the wrong place. This will output the IP address for every row in the csv file:

```
with open('servers.csv') as f:
read_data = csv.reader(f)
for row in read_data:
    print(row[1]) # IP address
```

Comment: This is something the OP has already attempted and is what causes an error.